# ajax chat interface not displaying message even on page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this javascript file which is supposed to get messages from PHP file through ajax mechanism, even tho the message get sent successfully nothing gets displayed on the screen but it's there in the PHP file and it is in the database as well. can anyone point out any mistake I am making, Is there an alternative way to make a chat interface? Here's the code for javascript file and HTML

```js
var pollServer = function() {
    $.get('chat.php', function(result) {
        
        if(!result.success) {
            console.log("Error polling server for new messages!");
            return;
        }
        
        $.each(result.messages, function(idx) {
            
            var chatBubble;
            
            if(this.sent_by == 'self') {
                chatBubble = $('<div class="row bubble-sent pull-right">' + 
                               this.message + 
                               '</div><div class="clearfix"></div>');
            } else {
                chatBubble = $('<div class="row bubble-recv">' + 
                               this.message + 
                               '</div><div class="clearfix"></div>');
            }
            
            $('#chatPanel').append(chatBubble);
        });
        
        setTimeout(pollServer, 5000);
    });
}

$(document).on('ready', function() {
    pollServer();
    
    $('button').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});

$('#sendMessageBtn').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    var message = $('#chatMessage').val();
    
    $.post('chat.php', {
        'message' : message
    }, function(result) {
        
        $('#sendMessageBtn').toggleClass('active');
        
        
        if(!result.success) {
            alert("There was an error sending your message");
        } else {
            console.log("Message sent!");
            $('#chatMessage').val('');
        }
    });
    
});
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align:center"></h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h2 class="panel-title">Let's Chat</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" id="chatPanel">
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="chatMessage" placeholder="Send a message here..."/>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button id="sendMessageBtn" class="btn btn-primary has-spinner" type="button">
                            <span class="spinner"><i class="icon-spin icon-refresh"></i></span>
                            Send
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="client.js"></script>
```

I also have CSS which I don't think could have impacted any output:

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors? Or used the network tools to check for a response from the ajax call?

Comment: I have checked the console there isn't any error. I did it everything is working fine? just message doesn't get displayed at all.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood it right, you´re mistaken at this point:

```
if(!result.success) {
    alert("There was an error sending your message");
} else {
    console.log("Message sent!");
    $('#chatMessage').val('');
}
```

You are returning your message, in case of success into a log file,
i think if you just do this will be enough:

```
if(!result.success) {
    alert("There was an error sending your message");
} else {
    $('#returning_div_id').html("Message sent!");
    $('#chatMessage').val('');
}
```

I´d suggest you to create this div at this point:

```
<div class="container">

    <div id='returning_div_id' class='alert alert-success'></div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
```

Comment: I did that it just displays the message that message is sent, that' not the dilemma I have how can I displays the messages sent from others.